# Crystal Reports 2016 unable to modify existing objects in sections

Tags: crystal-reports

I've run into an interesting problem. I've inherited some existing Crystal Reports from an employee who is no longer with my agency. In all of these reports, I am able to add new fields to any section I please. If it is the Details section, I am able to move and rearrange objects in that section. But when I try to move or rearrange items in Group Footers (and other areas), I am unable shift them around. I can add new fields without a problem. But if I try to grab a summary field (for example) with my mouse, it gives me the four arrow icon, but it simply slides off the object. I can cut and paste that same object to move it around the area, but that is not a tenable solution. Anyone have ideas regarding what the issue could be? It's CR 2016, support pack six, version 14.2.6.2839, running on a Widows 10 client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to check is if the Lock Size & Position property is enabled for the fields you cannot move or resize.  To do this, identify a field or object on the report that you are unable to move or resize, then right-click on the field or object and select "Format Field..."" or "Format Text...".  The text of this can vary depending on the type of object.

[image: See the highlighted text here.]

This will open the Format Editor window.  From here you will need to navigate to the "Common" tab in the Format Editor, and you will find a check box near the top of the window for "Lock Position and Size".  If this is checked, then you will need to uncheck it before you can resize or move the object.

[image: See highlighted section here.]

Also, you can selected multiple objects at once when doing this.  Otherwise, you will need to repeat these steps for each field on the report that you are unable to move or resize.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. That was exactly the issue. How my eyes slipped off this box for so long, I'll never know, but that problem is solved. Thank you so very much.